# Which Java Web Framework and Web Application Server to use?

Tags: java

I have intranet highly user interactive ASP.net applications, which now I am going to develop in Java as it is the requirement. I need to know what kind of java web frameworks should I use... full stack frameworks or MVC frameworks? I ll use jQuery, javascript, ajax and client and server side validation. Which framework is most suitable for my application? I need to know comparison of Glassfish, Websphere and Weblogic and any other application server. Which one is suitable for my web applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is never "the best web framework" or "the best application server". Each framework and server has its pros and cons.

I highly recommend to give yourself an overview about the different Java web frameworks currently available.

Which web framework and which application server best fits your need really depends on your application. Again, there's no "best product".

Evaluate the web frameworks together with application servers.